# SQL Server 2008 foreign key confilict

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

We have got table which has many rows. I want create foreign key between these two tables but 
I get the following error.

> *'CMEvent' table saved successfully;
>
>   'BaseEvent' table
>
>   Unable to create relationship 'FK_CMEvent_Oid'.
>
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CMEvent_Oid". The conflict occurred in database "CMO_RestoredData", table "dbo.BaseEvent", column 'Oid'.`*

Comment: Can you show the full definition of both tables? Have you verified that the child table contains only IDs that are actually present in the parent table?

Comment: Vague question, but normally would mean you're trying to add a foreign key where a constraint is violated because the second table doesn't contain a required relation. Post more detail and someone might be able to help you with a query to find the missing data.

Comment: This is a piece of my BaseEvent table                                    http://screencast.com/t/Hteavy0G                                        this is my CMEvent table                                               http://screencast.com/t/IMK0Mgkv

Comment: You need to show us the code and explain what you're doing. The error message just means you're trying to insert some data into a table that violates the FK constraint, e.g. you're trying to insert a value that doesn't exist in the referenced table.

Comment: Please, look at this video          http://screencast.com/t/N5wgQmA57hN

Comment: I define that some data doesn't exit in the referenced table,, and I add this data,, but problem doen't solve

Comment: Are the columns (`Oid`) in the two tables of the same datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to duplicate this error when I had a row in the CMEvent table that did not exist in BaseEvent.

Try running this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CMEvent c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM BaseEvent
  WHERE oid = c.oid )
```

If you get any rows back, these will have to be deleted before you can apply the foreign key constraint.

If you need to keep these orphaned rows, you can use [WITH NOCHECK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to only apply the constraint to new rows.